# Azure WebJob blade not showing - Web App not running

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I published a console application from Visual Studio 2015 to Azure as a WebJob ( free tier ). The console application takes around 10 minutes to run and complete, it periodically downloads around 100 3-5 MB files from a resource, and stores it in an Azure Blob. I want it to run every 1 hour.

When I try to look at the application service and it's WebJob blade, it shows this:
[image]

It seems that there is something wrong with the service, when I try to re-publish with Visual Studio the following error occurs:

```
    Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4283,5): Error ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC:
 Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer 
("webjobxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified 
process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure 
that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)
```

The only way that I can get it out of this state is by deleting the WebApp, and re-publishing as a completely new WebApp.

In addition, when browsing to the webapp, it displays

```
403 - This web app is stopped.
```

Any ideas why this happens? How do I diagnose it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thos most likely explanation is that your free Web App ran out of quota (CPU or memory) and was temporarily disabled. The old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/) shows this a better than the new one, so please check it out (look in the Dashboard tab).

Comment: Hello, I think you are right, I just upgraded to standard, and it no longer does this. it's a shame it's not more apparently the quotas that we are given, or that it doesn't tell me 'quotas exceeded', rather it just breaks and leaves me puzzled. Thanks

Comment: Agreed, it is something the new portal needs to handle better. The old one made that fairly obvious.